CS0115: 'addCategoryToDbAndSeedTable.BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override
I'm following this course on Udemy and after a lesson on refactoring, my project keep failing with this issue.
The comments in the course suggest, that my namespace is wrong, but it isn't (as far as I understand namespaces).
Some questions answered here also suggests namespaces, but I'm unable to mine out of the answers what namespace should change from what to what.
This feels like a simple solution, but I cannot find it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem indeed was namespaces.
However it might be worth (for some people) to understand), why was it so hard to identify what, where, from what and to what
If you did simple refactoring, like I did, then from what and to what are easy. It's OldProjectName -> NewProjectName
As for where, please look at the attached picture:

In my IDE (Visual Studio) I see one file less than on my filesystem (Note for mean people: yes, that's my bad, I'm aware)
The problem is that the issue comes from one file (.Designer.cs) and you need to update the namespace in the other (.cs)
Please note that even files in VS can be opened using the regular tree expand/collapse functionality.
